# How to publish a custom object in a open graph story with facebook android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

With the latest Facebook SDK Updates , I see there are ShareOpenGraphAction And ShareOpenGraphObject Classes along with the ShareDialog and ShareAPI . The ShareOpenGraphObject has methods to set the attributes inside the object somewhat like this :

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
    .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
    .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
    .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
    .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
    .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
    .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
    .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
    .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
    .build();
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("fitness.runs")
    .putObject("fitness:course", object)
    .build();
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();
```

How to use this API to share a Self-Hosted Object (Custom Object created and hosted on own Webserver using Open Graph Meta-Tags) ?

Please advise.